# Why wasn't Myrtle more involved with the Basilisk parts of the story?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

I was watching '*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*' and found myself with intriguing doubts.

Moaning Myrtle houses herself in the unused girl's bathroom in Hogwarts. She would be able to interact with anybody that comes in the bathroom. Having said this,

> **How did Myrtle not see Ginny Weasley being taken to the Chamber of Secrets in her trance state?**

Any activity in this particular bathroom will not take place without the knowledge of this ghastly girl. So how did she not know anything about Ginny's trance state and how she ended up in the Chamber? There is a scene when Myrtle weeps about someone throwing a book at her, but how come she didn't chase the person who threw the book at her? Come on, she's a ghost, and is fully capable of waltzing through the walls and following the person who threw it.

[image]

The second question is:

> **If Nearly-headless Nick was petrified by the Basilisk glance, why wasn't Myrtle's ghost ever petrified?**

[image]

There is a scene in which Justin Finch-Fletchley was found petrified, but did not die as he saw the snake through Nick. Now Nick hangs petrified, mid-air, even though he is already dead. How come Myrtle, who could've seen the Basilisk, more often than anybody, not be known to be petrified?

**NOTE**:
 
My knowledge on the series is highly limited, so please excuse any mistakes I may have made.

Comment: That's true. But Myrtle knows that Harry, Ron and Hermione have been coming into the bathroom lately, maybe that's why she does't come to them at each scene. But if the chamber is opened by Ginny, she would definitely know. Right?

Comment: These are all reasonable questions, but you've included *four distinct questions* in one post, which unfortunately makes this too broad. I've put it on hold for now, but please let me know if you [edit] to cut it down to just one question (or maybe two - your 1st and 2nd questions might be related enough to work together in a single post), and I'll reopen it. As others have said, it's better to post distinct questions separately - otherwise someone will post an answer solving questions 1-2, and someone else will post one solving questions 3-4, and which do you accept?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have pruned the post. I hope it is acceptable to be reopened.

Comment: @VarunNair Thanks! I reopened your question, and also edited your title in an attempt to describe both aspects of your current question (what were originally your 1st and 2nd questions) in a single query. I hope you re-ask your 3rd and 4th questions separately :-)

Comment: You are assuming too much. Why must she have absolutely seen Ginny entering the chamber or throwing the diary? Maybe Ginny just made sure there was no one around before opening the chamber. Tom would have learnt to be more thorough as Myrtle has once already been walked on him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Myrtle isn't always present in the main area of the bathroom, she often hides.

> Harry Potter: "Did you see anyone near here that night?"
>
> Myrtle: "I wasn't paying attention. Peeves upset me so much I came in here and tried to kill myself. Then, of course, I remembered that I'm — that I'm —"
>
> Ronald Weasley: "Already dead."

— The trio ask Myrtle about the attack on Mrs Norris [HP and the Chamber of Secrets]

2) It is never said Myrtle looked *in the eyes* of the basilisk when she's a ghost.